# A free sample web app for drawing GeoJSON

Tags: geojson, gdal

I am trying to figure out how much time can it take to develop a sample web app that loads maps in GeoJSON format from the server and draws them in the browser with JavaScript.

I have no experience of working with GeoJSON or drawing geospatial data with JavaScript and my idea is that the starting point to develop the app can be a JavaScript component that draws GeoJSON as demonstrated [here](https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/utils/geojson/), where my GeoJSON looks like [this](https://developernote.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/geojson-point.png).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use a tool like [HERE XYZ Studio](https://developer.here.com/blog/managing-and-visualizing-geospatial-data-here-xyz-now-in-beta) you upload GeoJSON data to style it, edit data in tabular form, etc. and can get the embed code to publish it in your web app.

There are a few tutorials, in particular the one that shows you step-by-step "Mapping Seismic Activity" from publicly available GeoJSON might be a good start.  The other tutorials show you how to do it with Leaflet or Tangram if you wanted to try building your own visualization with a different rendering library.